# About Class initialization in Swift 4

Tags: initialization, swift4

In regarding to the class initialization, I have a pieces of code as following:

```
class Parent {
    func parentMethod() {
        print("This is a parent class")
    }       
}
```

As I said, I decleared a `Parent` class without any initializer.

and I initialize a instance and call its method as:

```
var p = Parent()
p.parentMethod()
```

I am wondering do I have to declare an `init` method? or i only need to declear a initializer when properties is included in the class?

Comment: Right, in a class an initializer is only needed if there are non-optional properties. And this rule is valid for all versions of Swift.

Comment: Thanks, That is what I thought.